# PDO prepared statement wont work with this query

Tags: php, pdo, prepared-statement

Im having this query:

```
$query = $db->query("SELECT

                      posts.post_topic_id,
                      posts.post_content,
                      posts.post_id,
                      posts.post_date,
                      posts.post_by,    
                      posts.post_votes_total,
                      posts.post_suggested_amount, 
                      posts.post_accepted,
                      posts.post_last_edited,
                      posts.post_edit_sum,
                      users.user_id,
                      users.username

                    FROM
                      posts

                    JOIN
                      users
                    ON
                      posts.post_by = users.user_id
                    WHERE
                      posts.post_topic_id = :topic_id
                    ORDER BY
                      :sort
                    LIMIT :start , :per_page
                  ");

$query->bindParam(':topic_id', $topic_id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$query->bindParam(':sort', $sort, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query->bindParam(':start', $start, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$query->bindParam(':per_page', $per_page, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$query->execute();
```

But it wont execute and give me and error instead:

> exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ':topic_id ORDER BY posts.post_id ASC ' at line 25' in C:\htdocs\lr\topic.php:577 Stack trace: #0 C:\htdocs\lr\topic.php(577): PDO->query('SELECT???? ...') #1 {main}

If I don't prepare the statements, and I use the normal variables, the query executes just fine.

What's my mistake?

Comment: Another common problem: Ensure that `$start` and `$per_page` and `$topic_id` contain actual integer values. Use `var_dump()` to verify that.

Comment: `near ':topic_id ORDER BY posts.post_id ASC ' at line 25' ` it looks like the query you posted is not exactly the one giving the error? (yours here has ":topic_id ORDER BY :sort LIMIT")

Comment: Jup, even that, not using `prepare`. That needs fixing in the first place.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You mix up methods for prepared statements and simple queries. The `bindParam()` method just relates to prepared statements. On its own, the `query()` method tries to execute the given query immediately, which fails, because the parameters have not been substituted.

To solve this, just change to prepared statements all along by using

```
$query = $db->prepare("SELECT ... " );
```

and then execute after binding all variables

```
$query->exec();
```